# Rails 3 - index action not loading by default on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Now i have a fresh `rails 3` install running over `rvm 1.9.2` 
I generated a controller using the follow instruction:

```
rails generate controller blog index
```

The output is

```
      create  app/controllers/blog_controller.rb
      route  get "blog/index"
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/blog
      create    app/views/blog/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/functional/blog_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/blog_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/helpers/blog_helper_test.rb
```

but in browser when i try to get to `http://localhost:3000/blog` i get:

```
No route matches "/blog"
```

but if i type `http://localhost:3000/blog/index`

it renders the index view.

doesn't it works like Rails 2? where i get to the index view by default with just putting the controller name on the url ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For rails 3:

```
match '/blog', :controller => 'blog', :action => 'index'
```

Comment: It'd look better like this: `match '/blog' => 'blog#index'` don't you think?

Answer (score 10):

If you look into `routes.rb` you'll see

```
get "/blog/index" => "blog#index"
```

So just remove it with

```
get "/blog" => "blog#index"
```

or you can use `resources` here.

But only question: why do you use singular form? It is nonsensical to call `index` to `singular` noun. You should use or "blog#show" as a resource or "blogs#index" as a resources.

Conventions in Rails is a kind of basement. Don't break them if you can follow them

Answer (score 4):

Rails generate does not generate resources for your controller by default.  You specified one action for your controller, 'index', so in your case you end up with this in config/routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
    get "blog/index"
```

The simplest thing to do would be to change this to:

```
  get "blog", :to => 'blog#index'
```

ian.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, based on my experience with Rails 2, but here's what I think is happening:

If you'd generated your controller with the `scaffold` option (that's still in Rails 3, right?), it would have created a model in addition to your controller, and added the corresponding routes via a call to `map.resources` (or Rails 3 equivalent) - this last bit is what gives you the `/models` routes you're expecting.

But since you just generated the controller, no model was created, and thus Rails doesn't put in a `map.resources` statement in routes.rb - `map.resources` really only makes sense when there's a model underlying your controller.  In fact, I don't think it adds *any* special routes when you generate a controller; you're getting to your index by one of the default routes: `/:controller/:action`.

So if you want to get to your index from `/blog`, you'll have to add the route yourself.  Luckily, it should be a one-liner.

Hope this helps!

PS:  And if you're paranoid, you'll want to disable those default routes before you go to production - they allow GET requests to trigger actions that change your database (e.g. `GET:/blog/destroy`), opening you up to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Csrf) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your routes.rb file `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`
It's better if you add it at the bottom of the routes.rb file.
The problem with this approach is that it will make all your actions available through get request. So be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manual routing you can go to `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and add a blank index method

```
def index
end
```

make sure your generated controller extends the application controller, and *boom* all your generated controllers do what you want
Tested on Rails 3.2.*