# rails 3.0 locked on webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking at similar questions for hours and no joy, I am at my wits end. I have followed so many docunents, guides, tutorials and everything else on how to use the mongrel server in rails 3.0+. I have installed the mongrel gem, and included it in my gem file, but I just get a huge stack trace.

I am trying this command:

```
rails server mongrel
```

But I have also tried `rails script/server mongrel`

rails server simply uses Webrick every time.

The reason why I am so desperate to use mongrel, is because I am currently going through Sitepoint book Simply Rails 2, and I have just generated a model and controller. The controller was generated with `rails generate controller Stories index`. It then says you can start the server and open up the address (for webrick http://localhost:3000) /stories and it will contain the makings of the app. BUt I have to go to `stories/index` in order to get the desired view. I am wondering if this is because they use mongrel and I use webrick. If this is something else then problem solved anyway.

Comment: "the makings of the app" that sounds like the index.HTML file which is served from public directory at http://localhost:3000/ ? I don't think there will be any diff between the web servers while in development mode

Comment: 1: "huge stack trace" - what is the trace, please post? 2: You don't need to use mongrel. Just go to `http://localhost:3000/stories` to get where you want to go. It would be no different with mongrel. There is no advantage nor difference for you to choose mongrel in your case. Webrick will work just as fine.

Comment: @Casper that is the problem, when I go to /stories on its own I get a no route found for /stories (or something like that) but when I make it stories/index I get the page shown in the book as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question on the default route to your `Stories` controller, see this post:
[Rails 3 - index action not loading by default on controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794191/rails-3-index-action-not-loading-by-default-on-controller)

You need edit the default route in your `routes.rb` file to automatically load the `index` action. It doesn't have anything to do with mongrel vs WEBrick, it's simply a routing configuration issue.

Comment: Fantastic. I went into the routes.rb before posting on here, and it just had get "stories/index" no => anything. So I tries changing it to just get "stories/" but it was a massive crash. Now when I go get "stories/index" => "Story#index" it is perfect. BUt is there any way to make this behaviour default across rails3 apps?